# Stratified Sampling in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I've looked at the [Sklearn stratified sampling docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) as well as the [pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) and also [Stratified samples from Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41035187/stratified-samples-from-pandas) and [sklearn stratified sampling based on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36997619/sklearn-stratified-sampling-based-on-a-column) but they do not address this issue.

Im looking for a fast pandas/sklearn/numpy way to generate stratified samples of size n from a dataset. However, for rows with less than the specified sampling number, it should take all of the entries.

Concrete example:

[image]

Thank you! :)

Comment: I think the title of the question should be changed to reflect that the stratification is of a feature column, not the target column.

Comment: You could almost use the `imblearn` downsampling or undersampling techniques for this: https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/under_sampling.html

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Use `min` when passing the number to sample.  Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        A=[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4],
        B=range(10)
    ))

df.groupby('A', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.sample(min(len(x), 2)))

   A  B
1  1  1
2  1  2
3  2  3
6  2  6
7  3  7
9  4  9
8  4  8
```

Comment: @piRSquared, let's say I have a df with 1M rows, I want to sample 10k of it, with at least 10 samples from each user_id, how would you approach it?

Comment: @whitfa still works for me, and the linked change shouldn't impact it at all.  What version of pandas are you using?  I'm using `0.25`

Comment: Apologies @piRSquared, looks like I was mistaken!  I will delete my original comment.

Comment: When my grouping column has high cardinality this solution is quite slow. Which I guess makes sense. Anyways,   can you think of a way to speed it up in scenarios like this?

Answer (score 19):

Extending the `groupby` answer, we can make sure that sample is balanced. To do so, when for all classes the number of samples is >= `n_samples`, we can just take `n_samples` for all classes (previous answer). When minority class contains < `n_samples`, we can take the number of samples for all classes to be the same as of minority class.

```
def stratified_sample_df(df, col, n_samples):
    n = min(n_samples, df[col].value_counts().min())
    df_ = df.groupby(col).apply(lambda x: x.sample(n))
    df_.index = df_.index.droplevel(0)
    return df_
```

Comment: An explanation, what the posted code does and how this addresses the problem in the question, rarely fails to improve an answer.

Answer (score 10):

the following sample a total of N row where each group appear in its original proportion to the nearest integer, then shuffle and reset the index
using:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    A=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
    B=range(20)
))
```

Short and sweet:

```
df.sample(n=N, weights='A', random_state=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Long version

```
df.groupby('A', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.sample(int(np.rint(N*len(x)/len(df))))).sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: There is an issue with the short version, it is not keeping the origin proportions: it doesn't really make sense to use the parameter weights = the category column, e.g. it could a string. If you really want to use df.sample, you need to compute an additional column equal to the frequency of the category column.
But the long version works!

Comment: Short version doesn't work for me for binary data, e.g. `df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [np.random.randint(0, 2) for _ in range(100)]})`

Comment: Will not work if the column `A` is not numeric.

Answer (score 2):

So I tried all the methods above and they are still not quite what I wanted (will explain why).

###### Step 1: Yes, we need to `groupby` the target variable, let's call it `target_variable`. So the first part of the code will look like this:

```
df.groupby('target_variable', group_keys=False)
```

I am setting `group_keys=False` as I am not trying to inherit indexes into the output.

###### Step2: use `apply` to sample from various classes within the `target_variable`.

This is where I found the above answers not quite universal. In my example, this is what I have as label numbers in the `df`:

```
array(['S1','S2','normal'], dtype=object),
array([799, 2498,3716391])
```

So you can see how imbalanced my `target_variable` is. What I need to do is make sure I am taking the number of `S1` labels as the minimum number of samples for each class.

```
min(np.unique(df['target_variable'], return_counts=True))
```

This is what [@piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44115314/8653046) answer is lacking.
Then you want to choose between the `min` of the class numbers, `799` here, and the number of each and every class. This is not a general rule and you can take other numbers. For example:

```
max(len(x), min(np.unique(data_use['snd_class'], return_counts=True)[1])
```

which will give you the `max` of your smallest class compared to the number of each and every class.

The other technical issue in their answer is you are advised to shuffle your output once you have sampled. As in you do not want all `S1` samples in consecutive rows then `S2`, so forth. You want to make sure your rows are stacked randomly. That is when `sample(frac=1)` comes in. The value `1` is because I want to return all the data after shuffling. If you need less for any reason, feel free to provide a fraction like `0.6` which will return 60% of the original sample, shuffled.

###### Step 3: Final line looks like this for me:

```
df.groupby('target_variable', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.sample(min(len(x), min(np.unique(df['target_variable'], return_counts=True)[1]))).sample(frac=1))
```

I am selecting index 1 in `np.unique(df['target_variable]. return_counts=True)[1]` as this is appropriate in getting the numbers of each classes as a `numpy array`. Feel free to modify as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Based on user [`piRSquared`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44115314/16109419)'s response, we might have:

```
import pandas as pd


def stratified_sample(df: pd.DataFrame, groupby_column: str, sampling_rate: float = 0.01) -> pd.DataFrame:
    assert 0.0 < sampling_rate <= 1.0
    assert groupby_column in df.columns

    num_rows = int((df.shape[0] * sampling_rate) // 1)
    num_classes = len(df[groupby_column].unique())
    num_rows_per_class = int(max(1, ((num_rows / num_classes) // 1)))
    df_sample = df.groupby(groupby_column, group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.sample(min(len(x), num_rows_per_class)))

    return df_sample
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure when this was added to pandas but now you can [sample from groups](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html):

(using the DataFrame from @piRSquared)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        A=[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4],
        B=range(10)
    ))

df.groupby("A").sample(n=2, replace=True)
```

This provides a balanced sample of size 2 of each group specified in column `A`. The argument `replace=True` specified that oversampling is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do proportional sampling:

```py
frac = n/len(df)
strat_sample = df.groupby("A").sample(frac=frac)
```