# How to Stratify with more than one variable in python

Tags: python, pandas, sampling

I am doing a stratified sample with two variables. What do I need to alter when I am doing this with a dataframe?

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
Games_Sales=pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Jon\\Desktop\\data 
science\\GamesSales_Data.csv')
Games_Sales 


grouped_game_data=Games_Sales.groupby(['Year','Genre'])
year_gender=Games_Sales.Year.unique()
Games_Sample=pd.DataFrame()
for g in year_gender:
g_data=grouped_game_data.get_group(g)
g_data=g.grouped_game_data(n=5,replace=True, random_state=1)
Games_Sample=Games_Sample.append(sample_data, ignore_index=True)
print(Game_Sample)
```

I am fairly sure this would be wrong

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stratified Sampling in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114463/stratified-sampling-in-pandas)

Comment: Essentially, do the groupby suggested in the linked question, but use multiple columns in the groupby.

Comment: I am trying to a stratified sample with respect to two variables.

Comment: so something like this: g=Games_df.groupby(['Genre','Year'])