# Pandas stratified sampling based on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
| Cliid | Segment | Insert |
|-------|---------|--------|
| 001   | A       | 0      |
| 002   | A       | 0      |
| 003   | C       | 0      |
| 004   | B       | 1      |
| 005   | A       | 0      |
| 006   | B       | 0      |
```

I want to split it into 2 groups in a way that each group has the same composition of each variable in [Segment, Insert]. For example, each group would have 1/2 of the observations belonging to segment A, 1/6 of Insert = 1, and so on.

I've checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36997619/sklearn-stratified-sampling-based-on-a-column), but it only stratifies for one variable, it won't work for more than one.

R has [this function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/splitstackshape/versions/1.4.8/topics/stratified) that does exactly that, but using R is not an option.

By the way, I'm using Python 3.

Answer (score 12):

You can use sklearn's [train_test_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) function including the parameter `stratify` which can be used to determine the columns to be stratified.

For example:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df_train, df_test = train_test_split(df1, test_size=0.2, stratify=df[["Segment", "Insert"]])
```

Comment: `stratify` doesn't seem to work for multiple columns when there is no target variable. When I run your code, I get `ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [6, 1] `.
If I delete `stratify`, it works, however.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I changed `stratify=[["Segment", "Insert"]]` to `stratify=df[["Segment", "Insert"]]`

Comment: May I know why getting this ValueError: "The least populated class in y has only 1 member, which is too few. The minimum number of groups for any class cannot be less than 2".  Data is binary target, when passing all string columns to do stratify, getting the above error, but passing only target column, it works, also removing stratify it works, so whether removing stratify to be considering the split is stratified based on all columns

Comment: whether this approach is good https://stackoverflow.com/a/51525992/11053801